# Panning an Animated.View, after being scaled, inside boundaries of parent View

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am using [react-native-reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/) and [react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation) to create a view that allows you to "explore" what's inside of it (even if it exceeds its width and height).

Here's my `gestureHandler` that updates `translationX` & `translationY` variables, later used in `useAnimatedStyle` to "move" the `<Animated.View>`:

```js
const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
  onStart: (_, ctx) => {
    ctx.startX = translationX.value;
    ctx.startY = translationY.value;
  },
  onActive: (event, ctx) => {
    'worklet';
    translationX.value = ctx.startX + event.translationX;
    translationY.value = ctx.startY + event.translationY;

    // update state to view values on the screen as they change
    runOnJS(setPosition)({ x: translationX.value, y: translationY.value });
  },
  onEnd: () => {
    'worklet';
    const boundedX = clamp(
      translationX.value,
      (BOX_WIDTH - container?.width) * -1,
      0
    );
    const boundedY = clamp(
      translationY.value,
      (BOX_HEIGHT - container?.height) * -1,
      0
    );

    // create "bounce-y" effect when moving the box back inside the bounds
    translationX.value = withTiming(boundedX);
    translationY.value = withTiming(boundedY);

    // update state to view values on the screen as they change
    runOnJS(setPosition)({ x: boundedX, y: boundedY });
  },
});
```

This code "works" in the following case:

- I have a "visible area" of `width: 100, height: 100`
- "box" (element that is being panned) of `width: 160, height: 160`

Here's a gif ([click to view in full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7QUA.gif)):

[image]

I created an example as a [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/E25pVyRhg) displaying my problem. If you change `INITIAL_SCALE` in `Transforms.js` to `0.5` or just tap the pink box (it changes its scale to `NEW_SCALE`, see `onPress()`), panning in boundaries no longer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it was scaling the box using its origin (the center), so before applying the `scale` transform, I had to translate it to "fake" setting  its origin to the top left corner.

```js
{ translateX: -BOX_WIDTH / 2 },
{ translateY: -BOX_HEIGHT / 2 },
{ scale: scale.value }, // <- NOW I am changing the scale of the box
{ translateX: BOX_WIDTH / 2 },
{ translateY: BOX_HEIGHT / 2},
```

I also made a function for calculating the "edges" of the outer box that have in mind the pink box's scale:

```js
const getEdges = () => {
  'worklet';
  const pointX =
    (BOX_WIDTH * scale.value - VISIBLE_AREA_WIDTH) * -1;
  const pointY =
    (BOX_HEIGHT * scale.value - VISIBLE_AREA_HEIGHT) * -1;
  return {
    x: {
      min: Math.min(pointX, 0),
      max: Math.max(0, pointX),
    },
    y: {
      min: Math.min(pointY, 0),
      max: Math.max(0, pointY),
    },
  };
};
```

Here's a [working Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@fakeheal/pan-gesture-on-a-scaled-view) with these fixes.

Helpful information:

- [[Transforms] transform-origin support](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1964#issuecomment-121080460)
- [The Heart of React Native Transform](https://medium.com/swlh/the-heart-of-react-native-transform-e0f4995ebdb6)